# 502 Bad Gateway NGinx

Tags: linux, nginx, server

I'm using an Nginx server, never worked with one before so I apologize if I've missed something stupid but I'm new to all of this.

In my error.log I have:

```
[error] 2105#0: *87 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 86.58.251.66, server: premium.bookboon.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "premium.bookboon.com"
```

And I'm not sure why this error occurs. Here is my nginx.conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # nginx-naxsi config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
    ##

    #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

    ##
    # nginx-passenger config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
    ##

    #passenger_root /usr;
    #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

I've seen a lot of these issues being solved with by fixing some php-fpm option but the server I'm working with doesn't appear to use it, a quick `find / -name "php-fpm"` returns nothing so I'm at a bit of loss here.

/sites-enabled/default:

```
server {
       listen         80;
       listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

       server_name    premium.bookboon.com;
       return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    root /var/www/premium/web;
    server_name premium.bookboon.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/premium.bookboon.com_bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/premium.bookboon.com.key;

    location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to rewrite
        try_files $uri @rewriteapp;

    } 
    location @rewriteapp {
        # rewrite all to app.php
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /app.php/$1 last;
    }

    location ~ ^/(app|config|test)\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
    fastcgi_param ENVIRONMENT "prod";
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/premium_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/premium_access.log;

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This question appears to be [off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: The Nginx configuration file where FastCGI is specified is not `nginx.conf`. Try posting your `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` file

Comment: here you go, hope it helps, cheers!

Comment: According to the `fastcgi_pass` option, nginx is forwarding requests to the port 9000 of your host, but there is no program listening there. Is there not a step you missed in you deployment ?

Comment: For instance, is `php-fpm` (`php5-fpm` on debian) or an alternative installed and started on your server ? nginx can only act as a front/proxy or static file server. It cannot process PHP on its own, and that's why you need some other service for that.

Answer (score 0):

Nginx does, by itself not contain any components to execute PHP code. It needs PHP-FPM for that.

Your nginx is configured to use PHP-FPM, but (as you already said) PHP-FPM is not installed.

If you want to run PHP scripts, you need to install and configure PHP-FPM. Installation is done with `apt-get install php5-fpm` on Debian-based systems. You will usually also have to install several of the `php5-*` library packages. (Depends on the application you want to run, so either read its docs or try executing it and look for error messages.)

Configuring PHP-FPM is not complicated, the default should work. Note that your nginx is configured to communicate with PHP-FPM through a network socket! Make sure that in the file `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` the `listen` parameter is configured with the correct combination of IP address and port, e.g. `listen = 127.0.0.1:9000`.

You will usually also have to make a few edits in `php.ini`, but this is very specific to your use case and goes beyond this topic.